# Roundup years obtained from datediff function

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datediff

I would like to round up years based on the `datediff` function. Let's say I have two dates: `20/07/2015` and `11/10/1976`. After obtaining the difference, I divided the days by 365 days, to convert it to years. Hence I should be getting 38.79726027 years, where I round up and will get 39.

However, my `tqsl` script seemed to be not providing the expected answer. Can anyone help me with the query?

```
SELECT [Date of Birth], [Risk_Comm Date],
       ceiling(DATEDIFF(year,[Date of Birth], [Risk_Comm Date]))
       AS [Age Limit Check]  FROM [201610$_1]
```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` returns `int`s. There's nothing to round up or down from its return value. Is there any acceptable "slosh" in the rounding? I.e. could calculating months difference and dividing that be acceptable? Otherwise you have to do it in days but there are then issues with leap years. Since `DATEDIFF` calculates *transitions*, it will always produce a number that is equal or one less than the "human" value you might want.

Comment: In short words if you want to have not rounded years you should calculate it yourself like `DATEDIFF(DAY,'19761011','20150720')/365.00`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
ROUND(ceiling(DATEDIFF(year,[Date of Birth], [Risk_Comm Date])),0)
```

Will result : 39.0

And,

```
CAST(ROUND(ceiling(DATEDIFF(year,[Date of Birth], [Risk_Comm Date])),0) as int)
```

Will result : 39

But as per my knowledge `DATEDIFF` should return `INT` by default

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "rounded" age by considering both contenders and picking the one that is closest to the risk date. I'm using a CTE to pick the contenders here, other options may be `APPLY`:

```
declare @t table (DOB datetime not null, RiskDate datetime not null);
insert into @t(DOB,RiskDate) values ('19761011','20150720');

;With Contenders as (
    select
        DATEDIFF(year,DOB,RiskDate) as Age1,
        DATEDIFF(year,DOB,RiskDate)+1 as Age2,
        *
    from @t
)
select
    CASE WHEN
        DATEDIFF(day,RiskDate,DATEADD(year,Age2,DOB)) <
        DATEDIFF(day,DATEADD(year,Age1,DOB),RiskDate)
        THEN Age2
        ELSE Age1
    END as RoundedAge
from Contenders
```

By careful consideration of the order in which I place the arguments in the final `DATEDIFF` calls, I ensure that both expressions produce positive results.

In the event that it's exactly split between one age and the other, the above produces the lower age. If you would prefer the higher age in that situation, just swap `<` for `<=`.